# Android: after changing orientation, a duplicate layout appears under ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

The following image might further clarify my problem:

[image: output]

I have a `RecyclerView` that inside a `ScrollView`. Scrolling the view after changing the orientation produces an output like the screenshot. (NOTE: I'm not sure if changing orientation has anything to do with this issue as I can't scroll in portrait mode)

It is as if there are two identical layouts on top of each other, but when the user scrolls, only the topmost layout moves but the other one stays still.

Here's my xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_16">

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/question_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/zm_image_placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/doubt_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/question_image"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_8"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_56"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
            android:fontFamily="@font/gothambook"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/padding_8"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/padding_4"
            android:text="This is the comment added by the student. This is the comment added by the student. This is the comment added by the student. "
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/answer_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/doubt_comment"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/zm_image_placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/doubt_answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/answer_image"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_56"
            android:fontFamily="@font/gothambook"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/padding_8"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/padding_4"
            android:text="This is the comment added by the student. This is the comment added by the student. This is the comment added by the student. "
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Edit:** This problem also occurs in portrait mode **after I've changed orientation** (portrait -> landscape -> portrait). If I don't change the orientation, everything works fine.

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`  if you're using a recylcerview inside. Also, are you adding he recyclerview dynamically(in code)?

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan there's no recyclerview, just simple `TextView` and `ShapeableImageView`. And I've also tried using `NestedScrollView`, but it produced same result.

Comment: > I have a `RecyclerView` that inside a `ScrollView`.

Duplicates usually happen when views are added by code in onCreate, it renders over the existing views

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan in its corresponding java file, I just set the image and text from okhttp3 response. I did not manipulate the view in any other way (other than setting visibility to GONE if there is no text or image)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the Manifest solved the issue in this case.

It is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36615888/8192914)